# Two Different Types of Associatons on the Same Two Tables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models, users and themes, that I'm currently joining in a HABTM association in a themes_users table. Basically, after a user creates a new theme, it becomes available to other users to select for their own use.

However, only the original creator of the theme should have the ability to edit it. So, I need to have some other kind of association to handle that relationship, something like an created_by_id field in the theme.

In this way, the user model acts as two different roles: they can be an implementer of a theme AND/OR the owner of the theme. The implementer relationship is handled by the themes_users join table; the question is: What is the right way to handle this secondary association? Do I need to make users polymorphic and then make the created_by_id reference an "owner"? Or is there something easier?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I see that a User can create multiple Themes but can a User 'use' more than one at a time? or when in use is it the Users current theme?

Comment: Yes, which is why it's a HABTM association. The User can create multiple themes and use multiple themes: Think of the theme model like a document; so, you can have lots of documents available to lots of different users, but each document only one creator/editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should add the following association

```
class User < ApplicationController
   # a user can create many themes
   has_many :themes_created, :foreign_key => :creator_id, :class_name => "Theme"
end

class Theme < ApplicationController
   # add a creator_id column in your themes table
   belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User"
end
```

This way you can get all the `themes` created by some `@user` through

```
@user.themes_created
```

Comment: The problem is that because of the HABTM association that already exists via themes_users, there's already a "has_many :themes" and "user.themes" on the user model.

Comment: But you still can't use "user.themes"... Is it as simple as doing the same with the user class? Like, in User "has_many :mythemes, :class_name => 'Theme'" and calling via "user.mythemes" ? I doesn't seem like that should work...

Comment: Yes, that's what you have to do. If you look at my answer, I've used `@user.themes_created`. This works.